# ReactJS onClick setState not working inside child component

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to setState in child component. I want with onCLick function.

handleclick function

```
handleClick(index, practice) {

if (index.length > 1) {
  let lecture_count = this.state.data.subjects[index[0]].lecture_parent.length;
  let lecture = this.state.data.subjects[index[0]].lecture_parent[index[1]];

  let first_page = (index[1] == 0)  ? true : false;
  let last_page = (lecture_count - 1 <= index[1]) ? true : false;
  let have_practice = (lecture.practice.name) ? true : false;

  this.setState({
    first_page: first_page,
    last_page: last_page,
    have_practice: have_practice,
    index: index,
    practice: practice,
  });

  console.log('index', index);
  console.log('state', this.state);

}}
```

button

```
    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, [this.state.index[0],
      this.state.index[1] + 1], false)}>Next</Button>
```

console.log('index', index);

```
**index (2) [0, 1]**
```

console.log('state', this.state);

```
state 
last_page: false
first_page: true
**index: (2) [0, 0]**
have_practice: true
practice: false
ready: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass handleClick to arrow function so you do not need to bind it to this:

```
handleClick = (index, practice) => {
    Code here
}
```

Then pass it to onClick like this:

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Next</Button>
```

Comment: Hi Carlos,

Thanks for response. If i dont use bind, react throw Maximum update depth exceeded error.

Comment: Then just do so inside the constructor of your class. This.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);